# Android cards animation

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager, android-animation

What's would be the best strategy for making a stack of cards in Android that animate cyclically i.e. card on top when swiped goes to the bottom.

The approach I was going for is making the cards as layout files (with details filled in code) and then using the `ListView` type mechanism to make the views move in the desired way. However, I don't see a good way of taking care of the z-ordering in this approach.

Any ideas or links to libraries that do similar stuff is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a viewpager and then set pager transformation. You can customize the pagertransformation according to your need. ViewPager can be made cyclic. To start off you can check the developer site, they have the basic implementation of pagertransformer with viewpager.

Comment: Yeah... I went with a basic ViewPager but that takes the card off the screen instead of behind the card stack. I'll look into pagertransformation. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be more natural to create such animation not programatically but as a small movie. You can calculate what card is under the picture dynamically but shuffle it with hardcoded movie.

Comment: It's part of the user experience... they have to be able to select and click cards

Comment: Then i don't know what exactly you want, but i think it's possible to avoid program animation.

Comment: yeah.. it's hard to describe. Kinda like I want them to flick the card on top and it goes to the back of the pile but you can still tell that it's a pile of cards cause they are randomly out of alignment... so if there are three cards you see the one on top but you also see that there are more beneath it.